# JAX-RS interceptor mapping exceptions on void methods

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, void

I am trying to use an interceptor to introspect and change exceptions that occur on the backend. The interceptor looks something like this:

```
public class ApplicationErrorInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationErrorInterceptor.class);

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object handleException(InvocationContext context) {
        try {
            return context.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.errorf(ex, "An unhandled exception occured!");
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .entity("some custom 500 error text")
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

And the service using this interceptor looks something like this:

```
@Path("/somepath")
@Interceptors({ApplicationErrorInterceptor.class})
public interface SomeRestService {
    @POST
    @Path("getResponse")
    Response getResponse();

    @POST
    @Path("getVoid")
    void getVoid();
}
```

Assume the implementation for both of these methods throw an exception. I expect the exception to be mapped to a 500 server error with the supplied custom message in both cases. Unfortunately, the method returning void will get mapped to a 204 No Content response. If I remove the interceptor altogether, the default 500 server error occurs, which is at least the correct status code, but I lost the error customization

Comment: Did you think in ExceptionMapper?

Comment: I did not try an exception mapper yet, no. While it would probably suffice for the example given, it doesn't give access to the original response, which is something I generally want to be able to look at

Comment: This Interceptors looks like Spring AOP. I think you won't be able to customize the void method because you are intercepting the result of the method and it returns void not Response. Keep in mind the ExceptionMapper.

Comment: You're right, this kind of interceptor is too early and just eats the exception. The return value getting ignored makes sense, albeit it being a bit hard to notice and debug at first. I'll have to use an exception mapper or some other mechanism provided by JAX-RS

Comment: You should just return Response for the void method, just to keep it consistent.